# Como poner en mayúsculas el primer carácter de una cadena en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Resultado:

> Uncaught TypeError: str.charAt is not a function
>       at :2:5

```js
var str = $('ul.dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-submenu > a');
str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">PRIMER</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">SEGUNDO</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">TERCERO</a></li>
</ul>
```

¿Cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Pero los caracteres ya están en mayúsculas. ¿Quieres solo el primer caracter en mayúscula y convertir el resto a minúsculas?

Comment: Pero Diego, ten en cuenta que `str` no contiene un string.

Comment: @ReneLimon sii eso, primer caracter en mayúscula y el resto a minúsculas, ej;  "HOLA" converti a "Hola"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas en tu código:

1. La variable **str** es un objeto array de elementos HTML **A**
2. Estas utilizando **str** como si fuera una variable String o Cadena, pero no es asi.
3. Debes recorrer cada elemento de str y evaluarlos uno a uno.
4. Debido a que los textos ya están en mayúsculas, debes poner en minúscula las letras restantes.

Ejemplo

```js
var str = $('ul.dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-submenu > a');
str.each(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).text().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + $(this).text().slice(1).toLowerCase());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">PRIMER</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">SEGUNDO</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">TERCERO</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta! Estaba yo en ello, pero aun me quedaba rato ahahah +1

Answer (score 0):

```js
String.prototype.remplazar=function(index, character) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
}
var str = $('ul.dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-submenu > a');
str.each(function(current,index) {
  palabra=$(this).text().toLowerCase();
  palabra=palabra.remplazar(0, (palabra.charAt(0)+"").toUpperCase());
  $(this).text(palabra);
})
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">PRIMER</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">SEGUNDO</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">TERCERO</a></li>
    </ul>
```